# .htaccess rewrite url to strip a single GET value

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite my page like  `abc.com/profile.php?id=abc` to `abc.com/abc`

Can you guide me?
When I try to add the following line, i getting 500 page error

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /profile.php?id=$1 [L]
```

my htaccess

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /detail.php?type=$1&title=$2&id=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?pn=$1&type=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^contact-us.html$ contact-us.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^about-us.html$ /about-us.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^privacy-policy.html$ /privacy-policy.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^legal.html$ /legal.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^search$ /search.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^disclaimer.html$ /disclaimer.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^submit-job$ /submit-job.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: When I try to add the following line, i getting 500 page error RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /profile.php?id=$1 [L]

Comment: without adding this line all working fine?

Comment: Yes without adding this line working fine.

Comment: Jsut replace your line with this
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]*)$ /profile.php?id=$1 [L] you can access it abc.com/profile/abc